# C++ const array appending

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, compile-time

I have this program which consists of a loader and different statically linked modules. The entrypoint of the program goes into a loop which executes all the module initialization-routines. The function-pointers to these routines are stored in a constant array in the main.cpp file.

My problem is that everytime I want to add or remove one of the modules I have to modify the array.
I feel like there should be a method of automating this process. Is there a way to let the preprocessor load and parse a text-file holding the function-names? Or can I append new entries to the constant array from another .cpp file? How do I generate this array at compile-time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The easiest way would be to move that array into a separate file `cpp` and yes, genereate it before compilation. `Makefile`s or some similar majyyks would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who cares. I have actually solved my problem. Turns out that gcc has a feature 
called 'section' which lets you create static memory regions that can be extended multiple times
during compile-time by just specifying a declaration with this attribute. This created memory region
packs the inserted elements side by side zero terminated, which gives it the characteristics of an array sorta. The memory location, lets call our section "name", can be accessed by defining extern const char pointers named __start_name and __end_name. Thanks gcc. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the list of modules is known in compile time, while do not simple list them in makefile?

Comment: How would I generate the array from that list in the makefile?

Comment: it would be easy with a scripting language of your choice. I.e. check [lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html)

Comment: make_all_modules: *_modules.cpp

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I mean, list of modules can be presented in some other form, array is not single option. Some form of static object initializer could be used. So you create some class ListOfModules with static array of particular module representative object, and method put(Representative*). Than, some module creates static helper-object which calls ListOfModules::put(this) in own constructor. Thats all.

Comment: @SergeyProkhorov Since dynamic initialization is not guaranteed to be single-threaded, you'd need a mutex inside `ListOfModules`.

Comment: yes, sure. A bit more time will be taken by mutex but this is not a problem during initialization. Result is nice: modules will never bother you anymore.